# Where should my virtual environment be located?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Suppose I'm starting a new Python project. Its root directory at the beginning looks like this (for this example it would be a Flask project, but the question applies to any Python project):

```
myproject
    static
    templates
```

I want to use `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment for my project. Where should I create the directory to hold this virtual environment? Should it go inside the root directory of the project, like so?

```
myproject
    static
    templates
    env
    .gitignore # ignores env
```

Or should I put the `env` outside the root directory, like so?

```
myproject
    static
    templates
env
```

What is the standard way to do this?

Comment: One common practice is to put virtualenvs to the `~/.virtualenvs/<projectname>/`.